# Replace text inside a div

Tags: jquery, replace

How to replace text inside a div with other elements

```
<strong class="product-detail-final-price">
    <input type="hidden" name="priceId" value="2353">          
    <meta itemprop="price" content="3339">
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="CZK">
    <link itemprop="itemCondition" href="https://schema.org/NewCondition">
    <meta itemprop="warranty" content="20 let">

    3 339 Kč
    <span class="pr-list-unit">
    / balení
    </span>
</strong>
```

How edit text `3 339 Kč`? The text is dynamic. Insert `<span>` is not allowed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Learn [ask] and [mcve]. It's only a 5 minute read and will save you hours. We want to help, but we need some context. Please [edit] your question to reflect it. What else did you try? It also sounds a bit like a homework question. We don't write code for you here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the text node using `meta` tag( with help of [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property ) and update content by [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property. [Attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) can be used for selecting the meta tag.

```js
$('meta[itemprop="warranty"]')[0].nextSibling.textContent = 'New content';

// or 

document.querySelector('meta[itemprop="warranty"]').nextSibling.textContent
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong class="product-detail-final-price">
  <input type="hidden" name="priceId" value="2353">          
  <meta itemprop="price" content="3339">
  <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="CZK">
  <link itemprop="itemCondition" href="https://schema.org/NewCondition">
  <meta itemprop="warranty" content="20 let">

  **3 339 Kč**
  <span class="pr-list-unit">
  / balení
  </span>
</strong>
```

Answer (score 1):

So long as the value you want to retrieve is always the first child textNode within the container, then you can use `filter().get(0)`, like this:

```js
var newPrice = '1 234 Kč';
$('.product-detail-final-price').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3 && this.textContent.trim();
}).get(0).textContent = newPrice;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong class="product-detail-final-price">
    <input type="hidden" name="priceId" value="2353">          
    <meta itemprop="price" content="3339">
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="CZK">
    <link itemprop="itemCondition" href="https://schema.org/NewCondition">
    <meta itemprop="warranty" content="20 let">

    3 339 Kč
    <span class="pr-list-unit">
        / balení
    </span>
</strong>
```